# D7 Mixed menu (entity and content translation)

Tags: 7, routes, i18n-l10n

In my main menu I have mostly links to nodes that are translated with entity translation, so one node with the fields translated.
But I have two nodes which are translated with content translation, so each node is actually three seperate nodes (three languages).
Now I don't know how to implement these content translated nodes in the hierarchy of the menu.
To clarify, my menu should look like this:

Main Menu
-Menu Item 1 (entity translation)
-Menu Item 2 (content translation)
--Menu Item 2.1 (content translation)
--Menu Item 2.2 (entity translation)
-Menu Item 3 (entity translation)

My question is this, how do I make a menu item for items 2.1 and 2.2?
Since item 2 is actually three seperate nodes I don't know what to configure as the parent of item 2.1 and 2.2.

Thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've been thinking about this some more. Would it be possible to programmatically change the link of a menu item based on the language that is currently used?